# Is there any way to optimize this neo4j query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
match(a)
where a:value
    and lower("some value") in (split(lower(a.value), " "))
return id(a) as id ,length(split(lower(a.value), " ")) as s
order By s
```

Here I am trying to get the list of nodes of type `value` which contains the value "some value" getting the nodes who match exactly the value first but `length(split(lower(a.value), " "))` is duplicated. Is there any way to optimize this query?

Comment: It is clear what you are trying to do. Can you clarify, or at least give an example of a node with and the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
MATCH (a:value) WHERE lower(a.value) CONTAINS "some value" RETURN a
```

Note that CONTAINS doesn't boundary check, so "rawr" CONTAINS "aw" is true. Otherwise use WITH to hold the new variable ...

```
MATCH(a:value) 
WITH a as a, split(lower(a.value), " ") as values
WHERE lower("some value") in values 
RETURN id(a) as id ,length(values) as s 
ORDER BY s
```